# Удаление елементов JS

Tags: javascript

```js
function del(){
    var count = container.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
    alert(count);
    for(i = 2; i < count + 1; i++){
        var checkboxId = document.getElementById('checkbox' + i);
        if (checkboxId.checked == true){
            var delDiv = document.getElementById("section" + i);
            delDiv.remove();
            alert(checkboxId);
        }
    }
}
```

Код выше по задумке должен удалять div'ы в которых чексбокс активен, он это и делает, но после того как один раз удалишь он уже не находит следующие чекбоксы что шли после того div'a что удалился. Предпологаю я не верно очищаю масивы и он пытается найти их там где ничего нет уже. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Почитай про ES6. Во-первых, для объявления переменных используй const или let. Во-вторых, используй стрелочные функции и записывай их в переменные, в-третьих, используй forEach  вместо for, в-четвертых, `getElementById('checkbox' + i)` такая запись не сработает, нужно использовать другие кавычки, которые располагаются на одной клавише с буквой "ё", в-пятых, необязательно писать `if (checkboxId.checked == true)`, а можно просто `if (checkboxId.checked)`, в-шестых, используй современный метод `querySelector`, который поддерживает любые селекторы. Ну это так... По оформлению кода.

Comment: Можешь использовать ESLint (как подключить можно прочитать в интернете) и тогда все ошибки подобного рода будут подсвечиваться.

Comment: @hot_penguin `('checkbox' + i)` вполне сработает, обычная конкатенация строки. Автору: Нужен пример с воспроизводимой ошибкой (с минимальным HTML). Должно быть, проблема в нумерованных id: Считалка `i` в цикле всегда идет последовательно на `+1`, а после первого удаления у нумерованных `id` появляются "дырки" в нумерации. Используйте классы (без нумерации, одинаковые) + их индексы.

Comment: просто используйте `querySelector` вместо `getElementsByTag`. Потому что второй вариант делает динамические преобразования с коллекцией, и у вас смещается индекс.

Comment: @РоманТатаринов Длина коллекции надежно сохранена в переменной `count`, которая не меняется во время перебора)